# Congruence modulo n where one side is equal to 1

Tags: congruences, integers

In the Miller-Rabin test for prime numbers, there is a congruence in the form of 
$a^{n-1} ≡ 1$ (mod $n$).

I'm curious as to how $1$ modulo $n$ cannot just be written as $n$? And the left side expressed as the remainder of the integer division or something? Or can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulus is like a remainder. So what that is saying is that $\frac{a^{n-1}}{ n}$ has a remainder of 1. For example, $5 ≡ 1$ (mod 4) also $9 ≡ 1$(mod 4). $n$ would not be an answer to that, because $n≡0$ (mod n).

Comment: Let me quote the book: *Two numbers are said to be congruent modulo n if they both have the same remainder when divided by n. The remainder of a number a when divided by n is also referred to as the remainder of a modulo n, or simply as a modulo n.* So as far as I understood it, they're saying that $a^{n-1}$ and $1$ are congruent modulo $n$, which means that they have the same remainder when divided by $n$. So I'm not sure in your answer...

Comment: If you think about it, if $n=4$, $a^{n-1}$ is not going to equal 4. Rather, when $a^{n-1}$ is divided by 4, the remainder is 1.

Comment: OK thanks, I just found the terminology and formulation used in the book quite confusing.